# flake8 not reporting on lines that are too long

Tags: python, pyflakes, flake8

If I create a file `test.py` with the following poorly-formatted contents:

```
import re
long_string = "foooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
class Foo():
    pass
```

and run `flake8` on the file from the command-line like this:

```
$ flake8 --max-line-length=79 test.py
```

only two errors are reported:

```
test.py:1:1: F401 're' imported but unused
test.py:3:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 0
```

The `max-line-length` violation on line two is not reported.

Completely by accident (I was testing if *any* of the command options would be respected), I found that if I add an ignore option like this:

```
$ flake8 --max-line-length=79 --ignore=E302 test.py
```

Then the line length violation *is* reported:

```
test.py:1:1: F401 're' imported but unused
test.py:2:80: E501 line too long (97 > 79 characters)
```

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and my `flake8` version info is:

```
2.5.4 (pep8: 1.7.0, mccabe: 0.2.1, pyflakes: 1.1.0) CPython 3.5.1+ on Linux
```

When I posted [a related questio](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/22580/8430)n on the Emacs Stack Exchange site (I thought the issue was with an Emacs package initially), one of the users there pointed out that  [`flake8` 2.5.4 requires a lower version of `pyflakes`](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/blob/e2d6f33151f42245c038ca55b53bc0dd199147f4/setup.py#L52). However, installing `flake8` through `apt` or `pip` automatically installs that particular version of `pyflakes` as a dependency, and I have been unable to get an older version of `pyflakes` to see if that solves the problem (maybe that is another question altogether).

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`E501` is being ignored somewhere. It's either in `~/.config/flake8` or in the local directory in `tox.ini`, `setup.cfg`, or `.flake8`. Somewhere in one of those files you will probably find something akin to:

```
[flake8]
ignore = E501
```

(You may see it among other error codes too.)

This is **not** a bug in Flake8, and is almost certainly something in your environment causing this. The reason you see `E501` is because you override the config file setting by providing `--ignore` on the command line.

Comment: Well, I feel stupid now. I had added `ignore = E501` to my `~/.config/flake8` at my previous job. Recently I updated my config by adding `max-line-length = 80`, but kept the `ignore` line, not realizing what `E501` corresponded to...I assume then, that when I added `--ignore=E302` as a command-line option, I was this overriding the `ignore` options in the `~/.config/flake8`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's exactly what you did. I was in a rush when I answered earlier and meant to mention that.